# Why can't I properly extract tokens using delimiters in this code?

Tags: c, arrays, char, delimiter, strtok

I'm writing code to extract all words from a .txt file, but am running into trouble. I want to only allow letters and apostrophes, hence the delimiters I chose. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    const char *separators =
    "\n\r !\"#$%&()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~";
    size_t len = 1000;
    char *word2 = (char *)malloc(len);
    FILE *file2 = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    if (file2 == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open second file for reading\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(word2, sizeof(word2), file2))
    {
        char *token = (char*)strtok(word2, separators);
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", token);
            printf("\n");
            token = strtok(NULL, separators);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is what is in words.txt:

`This is a sentence in the file`

My output ends up being

```
This
is
a
sent
ence
in
the
fi
le
```

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: One of the most basic (but valuable) debugging techniques for when you don't understand why you get a result is to print the data that the computer reads so you know what it got, rather than what you think it got.  For example, in the top of your loop, add `printf("Line: [[%s]]\n", word2);` (making sure to include a newline in the output so it appears timely.  If you'd done that, you'd have either resolved your problem immediately, or you would have been asking a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `sizeof(word2)` is 4 (`word2` is a pointer, so it's 4 bytes long). So you only ever ask for 4 bytes from the input file. Use `len` in your `fread` instead and it should work better.

Comment: Ah, don't know how I missed that. I figured something was wrong with my strtok usage. Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: I think that the OP is a 64-bit machine as it gets 7-character segments to split up.